# Sorting column A with drop-down and column B with checkbox

Tags: formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup, sorting, data-validation

I have a spreadsheet that I use to run a foosball tournament, and in column A I have a dropdown data validation that will let me select a players name. In Column B I have a checkbox that I check once a player has paid their entry fee.

I have another column in the sheet that takes the values from column A and sorts them into player/teammate, and in order to get a randomized team, I select all players in column A and do a randomize sort on that range. However, the checkbox in column B does not follow where the data in column A goes, mixing up who has paid and who hasn't.

Is there a way to make it keep column B selection matched up with the player name in column A?

I have searched quite a bit on this but haven't come across anything helpful.

Comment: Welcome. What web application are you using?

Answer (score -1):

**option 1:**

```
=QUERY(SORT(INDIRECT("A1:B"&COUNTA(A1:A)),
 ARRAYFORMULA(RANDBETWEEN(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:B"&COUNTA(A1:A)))^0, 100)), 1), 
 "where Col2 is not null")
```

[image: 0]

---

**option 2:**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D1:D, A1:B, 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]